# Vscode WSL Development

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Why am I unable to open a project from wsl2 in vscode using code .

After updating Vscode, Anytime I try opening project from my wsl2 with code ., which should work normally as expected but instead, I receive
`node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-       20.04\home\dexter\workspace\LeanIcon\gen_dashboard'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:987:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:832:27)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}`
```